# how to ignore printing Max depth limit reached go colly

Tags: go, go-colly

i have a go colly crawler that i am trying to crawl many sites . on my terminal it prints a lot of :

```
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
2023/05/30 02:22:56 Max depth limit reached
```

it makes it hard for me to read some prints that i have placed . i wanted to know if there is any way to ignore printing this in termial . thanks

Comment: Are you sure `gocolly` logs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Max depth limit reached` is [colly.ErrMaxDepth](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocolly/colly/v2#pkg-variables). There must be codes like this in your project:

```golang
c := colly.NewCollector(colly.MaxDepth(5))

// ...

if err := c.Visit("http://go-colly.org/"); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

If you don't want to log this error, add a simple check to exclude it:

```golang
c := colly.NewCollector(colly.MaxDepth(5))

// ...

if err := c.Visit("http://go-colly.org/"); err != nil {
    // log the error only when the error is not ErrMaxDepth.
    if err != colly.ErrMaxDepth {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Another option is to redirect the output to a file:

```
go run . 2>&1 >log.txt
```

or copy the output to a file and also to standard output with `tee`:

```
go run . 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Comment: that did the job i didnt know the maxDepth has special error type thanks <3